# wrap useDispatch and useAppSelector with custom hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-hooks

I have the following functions and components in my project:

**store.ts :**

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { authDialogReducer } from './authentication/authenticationReducer';
import { toastReducer } from './toast/toastReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    authDialog: authDialogReducer,
    toast: toastReducer
})

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer
})

export type AppState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

**hooks.ts :**

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { AppDispatch, AppState } from './store';

export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<AppState> = useSelector;
```

Suppose in my project from one of my components, which is called **`AuthDialog`** I want to use `useDispatch` and dispatch an action like this:

```
    const AuthDialog: React.FunctionComponent<AuthDialogProps> = (props) => {
    const authDialogState = useAppSelector((state) => state.authDialog);
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    const dispatchAuthDialog = (isOpen: boolean) => {
        dispatch({ payload: { isOpen: isOpen }, type: TOGGLE_AUTH_DIALOG } as ToggleAuthDialog)
    };
    const onCloseDialogClick = () => {
        dispatchAuthDialog(false);
    }
    const onSubmitClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {

    }

    const onTabChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, newValue: number) => {

    }

    return <Dialog className={Classes.Root} open={authDialogState.isOpen}>
        <DialogContent className={Classes.Content}>
            <div className={Classes.AuthDialogIcon}>
                <LockOpen />
            </div>
            <AuthDialogTabs onTabChange={onTabChange} />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
            <ButtonGroup>
                <CommonButton color="danger" onClick={onCloseDialogClick} title="خروج" />
                <CommonButton color="success" onClick={onSubmitClick} title="ثبت" />
            </ButtonGroup>
        </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
}
```

If I want to call the `TOGGLE_AUTH_DIALOG` action everywhere that it is used, I should repeat these lines of codes:

```
const authDialogState = useAppSelector((state) => state.authDialog);
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
const dispatchAuthDialog = (isOpen: boolean) => {
    dispatch({ payload: { isOpen: isOpen }, type: TOGGLE_AUTH_DIALOG } as ToggleAuthDialog)
};
```

So I decided to make it better and, instead of repeating the mentioned codes, create a hook for every action that I want to dispatch, like:

```
export const useAuthDialog: () => readonly [AuthDialogState, (isOpen: boolean) => void] = () => {
    const authDialogState = useAppSelector((state) => state.authDialog);
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    const dispatchAuthDialog = (isOpen: boolean) => {
        dispatch({ payload: { isOpen: isOpen }, type: TOGGLE_AUTH_DIALOG } as ToggleAuthDialog)
    };
    return [authDialogState, dispatchAuthDialog] as const;
}
```

After I did, **`AuthDialog`** would be changed to:

```
const AuthDialog: React.FunctionComponent<AuthDialogProps> = (props) => {
    const [authDialogState, toggleAuthDialog] = useAuthDialog();
    const onCloseDialogClick = () => {
        toggleAuthDialog(false);
    }
    const onSubmitClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {

    }

    const onTabChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, newValue: number) => {

    }

    return <Dialog className={Classes.Root} open={authDialogState.isOpen}>
        <DialogContent className={Classes.Content}>
            <div className={Classes.AuthDialogIcon}>
                <LockOpen />
            </div>
            <AuthDialogTabs onTabChange={onTabChange} />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
            <ButtonGroup>
                <CommonButton color="danger" onClick={onCloseDialogClick} title="خروج" />
                <CommonButton color="success" onClick={onSubmitClick} title="ثبت" />
            </ButtonGroup>
        </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
}
```

Finally, can this kind of change affect the performance of my code? Is it a good thing or not? Because when I have a lot of custom hooks, getting state from `useAppSelector` is repeating, and If I want to use multiple hooks in the components, I should write something like:

```
const [authDialogState, toggleAuthDialog] = useAuthDialog();
const [toastState, toastDialog] = useSuccessToast();
```

Comment: That's a really good practice, not just because it follows DRY requirements, but because it doesn't couple implementation details of your interface with the React component, this, way , if in future you want to get rid of Redux and use another state manager for example, you could refactor your whole codebase in just one day, by changing those hooks, and not having to touch the React Components. It's always a good practice to work this way, to place an abstraction layer interface between your view components and the state management logic.

Comment: @CesarePolonara Thank you for the answer! So as I understood from your answer, you advice that I can follow these way, yes? It doesn't have any negative effect to my code? Because with previous implementation, I just get the state once and now inside every hook I get the state separately!

Comment: If you are worried about performance issues, no, it won't have any. The only concern should be about code maintenance. React takes code inside custom hooks and parses it as if it was written in your component, so you are just adding a very small overhead of a function execution.